# Replace all instances of a string but the first one

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to clean up text in a MS Word file.

I receive text from a web form like this and then get it as a Word file.

```
Confirmed: Something
Confirmed: Else
Confirmed: every
Confirmed: time
```

I would like to get rid of all the "Confirmed" but for the first one, to get something like the following.

```
Confirmed:
   Something
   Else
   every
   time
```

I count all the words with

```
Function CountOccurrences(ByVal strToCount As String) As Integer

    Dim iCount As Integer
    iCount = 0
    
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Text = strToCount
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        Do While .Execute
            iCount = iCount + 1
        Loop
    End With
            
    CountOccurrences = iCount
    
End Function
```

I found articles on how to delete just the first one, or the last one, but can't figure out, how to delete all but the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub tester()
    Dim col As Collection, i As Long
    
    Set col = AllOccurrences("Confirmed:")
    For i = 2 To col.Count
        col(i).Text = vbTab 'replace the text with a tab
    Next i

End Sub

'Return a collection with all instances of strToMatch in the activedocument
Function AllOccurrences(ByVal strToMatch As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    With rng.Find
        .Text = strToMatch
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        Do While .Execute
            rv.Add ActiveDocument.Range(rng.Start, rng.End)
        Loop
    End With
    Set AllOccurrences = rv
End Function
```